# Calling C# function from C++?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, mono, xamarin.ios

I'm writing an app in monotouch which also makes use of a C++ library, so I've been using p/inoke to call C++ functions from C# to do a variety of things. However there is emerging a few scenarios where I would like the C++ code to call C# functions instead.

So something like:

```
void CPlusPlusFunction(Pointer* stuff)
{
    //do stuff

    CSharpFunction(*stuff);
}
```

Is this possible and if so how can I go about it? Perhaps instead of calling a function would it be possible to pass in a delegate to C++ to invoke and if so how would that work? All I really want to do is pass some information to C# immediately at that point in a function.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. However the AOT compiler, used for MonoTouch code compiled for devices, must be aware of such callback so it can generate the appropriate code. As such your callbacks must be decorated with the **[MonoPInvokeCallback]** attribute.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/#Reverse_Callbacks

Answer (score 2):

You can ask C# to export functions from a shared library, just as native libraries can do. In addition, C# can convert delegates to function pointers of the same signature, which you can pass into C++.

Comment: Could you provide us a simple example?

Comment: Here is an example how C# uses a delegate (callback EnumWindowsProc) and passes it to the C function EnumWindows() as IntPtr. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Enumerate-top-level-9aa9d7c1